# Changing Where CKEditor Looks for Images

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am wondering if there is some way to change where CKEditor looks for images. Right now it uses the location of the web page containing the editor as the root directory but I would like to write a javascript function that can change this directory to any arbitrary path passed to the function.

The bigger picture for this is that I'd like to extend the functionality of CKEditor to be able to save the source it creates to whatever location is picked by the user. I've already implemented getting the source and saving it using wxWidgets but am having trouble getting CKEditor to change its working directory so that images can be included from the directory the user picks.

I've tried using some of the properties like baseDir, basePath, and baseHref to make this possible but as far as I can tell none of them quite do what I'm looking for.

So the process would be:
(1) The user picks a directory where the source will be saved
(2) The user creates a page using CKEditor where images from the directory chosen can be included AND DISPLAYED in CKEditor
(3) The user saves the source of their page to the chosen directory (the source saved here should use the relative path to the images because the source is now located in the same directory as the images it includes)

I realize this is a rather unconventional use of CKEditor but if someone might be able to kick me in the right direction to making this happen, I'd really appreciate it.

EDIT:
So after a little experimenting and changing some backslashes to regular slashes, it looks like the baseHref attribute does what I'd like. I've still not been able to change its value at runtime though as I would like. Does anybody know if this is possible with CKEditor? I'd still like to have a javascript function that I can pass a path to and have it change this baseHref value. Right now I have set its value in config.js.

If this isn't possible, I know you can read and write the source in and out of the editor. So I would like to resort to reading and storing the source from the editor, reloading CKEditor with a new config.baseHref, and then writing the source back into the editor. Does anyone know if the CKEditor api provides functionality to reload its configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't expect too many people will be trying to do what I was doing here since CKEditor is usually hosted on a server somewhere, but in case someone finds it helpful, here's what I ended up doing.

As I mentioned in the edit to my question, modifying the baseHref gave me the functionality of prepending the image filename with the directory path leading to it. I wasn't able to find a way to modify it while the editor was running so I ended up telling CKEditor to load an external configuration file each time it started with the line

`config.customConfig = 'C:/Users/kenwood/Desktop/MarkCreator2/ckeditor/custom_config.js';`

Then I used C++ to write new contents to custom_config.js any time I wanted to switch directories.

Unfortunately this method meant I had to read the contents out of the editor, refresh the page, and then write the editor contents back in any time I wanted to change directories. This was adequate for what I needed though.